# Is it possible to modify the order in which MQ FTE picks the file from source path?

Tags: copy, ibm-mq, file-transfer, alphabetical, websphere-mq-fte

MQFTE picks the files and copies in the destination by alphabetical order (if I am not wrong). Is it possible to pick the files from the source path by file size or by file extension or any other order. If not can it be customized by any other means?

Comment: Any ideas about this ???

Answer (score 1):

You can customize your transfer with ANT script. I tried & it works.